# Perl: Reading from a 'tail -f' pipe via STDIN

Tags: perl, stdin, tail, output-buffering

There were a number of other threads like this, but the usual conclusion was something like "Install File::Tail".  But, I'm on an old box that we're decomissioning, and I just want to write a one-liner to monitor a log.  I tried installing File::Tail, but the environment for CPAN just isn't working, and I don't want to take the time to figure out what the problem is.

I just want a basic script that parses out an IP address and keeps a count of it for me.  For some reason, though, even this simple test doesn't work:

```
$ tail -f snmplistener.log|grep IPaddress |perl -ne 'print "LINE: $_\n";'
```

I think it has something to do with output buffering, but I've always been a bit fuzzy on how that works.  How can I get this one-liner working?

Comment: It's not output buffering - it's input buffering. Perl won't read from stdin automatically, you'd need a `while(<>) { echo $_ }` type thing going.

Comment: False economy. If CPAN doesn't work, you can always [download the distro](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MG/MGRABNAR/File-Tail-0.99.3.tar.gz) and [install it manually](http://p3rl.org/modinstall).

Comment: Do you have that problem if you remove `grep(1)` and just `perl -lne 'print "LINE: $_" if /IPaddress/'` ?

Comment: @MarcB, the `-n` adds a `while (<>) { ... }` around the provided code.

Comment: @MarcB - he's thrown the `-n` flag.  Perl will read from `<>` automatically :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tail -f` doesn't generally buffer output, but `grep` probably does. Move the "grep" functionality into your Perl one-liner:

```
tail -f snmplistener.log | perl -ne 'print "LINE: $_\n" if /IPaddress/'
```

Comment: I've never seen gnu grep buffer output. tail -f|grep on an apache logfile always shows up the grepped lines immediately.

Comment: Oh, DUH.  Ok, it works now.  Marking you as answerer in 2 minutes.

Comment: @MarcB, probably because output to a terminal is line-buffered by default, so you'd see it when tailing logs on the console.  Try `tail | grep | cat -` or similar.  Related, it's GNU grep, I believe, that supports the `--line-buffered` switch. :)

Answer (score 2):

man grep

```
--line-buffered
      Use line buffering on output.  This can cause a performance penalty.
```

so:

```
tail -f /log/file.txt | grep --line-buffered SomePattern | perl ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without using tail at all:

```
perl -e 'open($h,$ARGV[0]); while (1) { /IPaddress/ and print "LINE: $_" for <$h>; sleep 1 }' snmplistener.log
```